# Constructing 95% confidence intervals on the average SD value

Tags: confidence-interval

If I have one sample with repeated measurements I can construct a 95% confidence interval on the standard deviation using the Chi-Square distribution. What if I have multiple samples, each with their own SD value and I want an average SD value with 95% confidence intervals? Do I still use the Chi-Square distribution where the degrees of freedom are related to the number of SD values?

The fact that I'm unable to find any examples online tells me that maybe this isn't something normally done. My goal is to summarize sample variability (SD/CV) from several biological replicates with a single parameter if possible.

Comment: For this to make any sense, you will need to define -- quantitatively -- what you mean by "an average SD value."  For summarizing variability, either there is no significant evidence the various underlying SDs differ, in which case you can use a *pooled SD* (as computed in ANOVA, for instance); otherwise, it wouldn't be appropriate to use a single number to characterize the variability, would it?

Comment: The mean SD value, or is there something better?

Comment: It's hard to see how a mean SD would be useful for this purpose.

Comment: I don't expect biological samples to have the same variability and I'm not testing for significant differences either, but I thought there would be a simple way to show the variability in the SD. I want to know when the SD reaches a threshold value given a categorical factor with multiple ordered levels and make a general statement taking into consideration biological variability. For one sample I would check if the 95% CIs contain the limit. For multiple samples I thought I could show some kind of average SD values and their respective 95% CIs for simplicity.